# add specific font phpmailer or swiftmailer in html formating

Tags: php, css, phpmailer, swiftmailer

I want to send email with phpmailer with the specific hindi and punjabi font. These fonts are added in my website with the @font-face css.
I am Searching for that from many day. And also concerned with my hosting end, but they have not any solution. because email can't support the external stylesheet.

Comment: A font used in an email will only show if that font is installed on the recipients' computer - therefore you have to stick with common fonts.

Comment: Yeah, what @Adam says. Font-face is not an option with E-Mails - you're lucky if you get basic CSS working.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, this can't be achieved reliably across all email clients. Here, we usually just use system fonts for body copy and save out any titles/headers/buttons which use custom fonts as images.

You can use the `@import` method to a very limited extent. Here's [a blog post](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3897/) by Campaign Monitor, which helps to explain it a little more. If you want to target & support the likes of Outlook 2003 & 2007, be prepared to take a step into the [dark ages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa338201%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Using https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer you can compose a plain-text email and a HTML email.

A plain text email is just that. Text. Which will be rendered in the email clients default font. It's more like a compatibility mode for email clients that dont support html emails. If you are planning on sending HTML composed email messages i recommend that you add this, just incase.

A Html email supports html and (basic) css. CSS will be limited and really depends on the email client what it does and doesn't support. Newer email clients might support @font-face but slightly older email clients don't support this. Just keep in mind, if @font-face is not supported it will use the systems default font.

You can just use inline styles and import a font using a web url.

```
<style> @font-face{ font-family: justafont; src: url(http://url.com/font.woff);} </style>
```

I don't know if hindi is still readable in a normal font, lets say arial. But if so, i don't see the problem. People who have a email client supporting fancy css will get a nice hindy font, people who dont have this luxury will not. However if this is not the case i recommend to make it readable to all and not just to people with a fancy email client.